# Sending simple email from static page

Tags: docpad

I'm new to DocPad. I really like the idea of static page generation and had this in mind for some time, but great that there's already a mature project out there!

However, while I get a rough picture of how DocPad works, what would you recommend be the best way of creating a simple Contact Me page, that would email the input text to a specific address?

There is still requirement for server side code for this. How I see doing it right now, is having a html form doing a POST to nodejs server that will handle sending the email.

Is that a correct DocPad way of doing it, or I'm missing something?

Comment: yeah, I have the same problem too!

Comment: me too, thats why i developed the plugin @balupton is mentioning in the next answer :D

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [contactform plugin](https://github.com/dospuntocero/docpad-plugin-contactform) :)